# Rspec: How to test method contents if it eventually raises exception?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method:

```
  def post
    ...
    if res.failed?
      SlackNotifier.notify("Failed", { :channel => "#bugs" })
      raise "Boom"
    end
    res
  end
```

And in rspec I'm trying to test this, but it fails with a `RuntimeError` because the method eventually raises an exception:

```
it 'posts to slack' do
  allow(SlackNotifier).to receive(:notify)
  subject.post
  expect(SlackNotifier).to have_received(:notify).with("Failed", { :channel => "#bugs" })
end
```

How would I stop it from failing because of that `raise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stubbing raise on the subject fixed it:
`allow(subject).to receive(:raise)`